# How to make headers (dynamically) in android?

Tags: java, android, html, css, image

I can't really find alot of information on this; But I want to make a nice header were the left and the right side are static and the middle part gets dynamically generated based on 1 image.

For instance you have:

[image: left static] [image: the image that should get duplicated based on the width] [image: right side]

At the same time I want to be able to write some text in the middel part :). This is something that is very common in html, but I cannot find how to do this on android?

Comment: Have you read about [`Nine-patch`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) images?

Comment: Nope I haven't, But right here I'm starting from 3 seperate images. It looks like Nine-patch images are build from 1 image. I'll guess I'll have to paste together or something and then use the tool to make the image. Let me get on that :) Thx 

EDIT: I used this method to solve the problem. I simple made one image out of the above images, used a nine-patch tool and volia! It works and it's pretty good. Although the quality could be better anyway It will do for now.